# Validate List elements with Jackson

Tags: java, validation, annotations, jersey, jackson

I am using Jersey, Jackson for creating RESTful services.
The validation of input messages is done using annotations provided by `javax.validation`.
It is working fine except that now I have to add a member of type `List<Integer>`.

I want to add below two validations to it:

1. the size of list cannot be more than 3
2. the elements in the list can only have values in this range 1..99

I know how to add first validation. But I don't know how to add the second one.
Here is my code:

```
@Size(max = 3, message = "There cannot be more than 3 codes")
private List<Integer> codes;
```

Comment: Looks like you need a custom javax.validation.ConstraintValidator.

Comment: @user2953113: Ok. If that is the only option I'll do it. I am just checking if there is already something out there as this is not a very rare scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to implement your own List. You should just use ArrayList as a base class and then extend the methods you want to have your custom error handling.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you completely. Why do I have to implement my own List? Would a custom javax.validation.ConstraintValidator not be enough as mentioned by   user2953113 in the comment?